# how to get current day in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.8

I'm building an app which needs to function depending on the current day. I've googled but returned with no results. Is there any function in C# that will return the current day depending on system time? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.Day;
```

More info is found in the actual documentation from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried DateTime.Now.Day? Sorry but I can´t comment yet.

@edit

For more information about the DateTime class, take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: I would suggest you edit your post to include more helpful information. Take this link for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to display the date as: MM/DD/YYYY

```
string fullDate;
string date = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
string month = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
string year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();

fullDate = month + "/" + date + "/" + year;
```

Comment: Rather than concatenate 3 strings and have to allocate memory for each one, and rather than write 4 lines of code, and rather than declaring 4 string variables, how about DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")?

Comment: @BillGregg I had not idea you could do that. lol
I'll look into it tonight. :) Thanks